# How to import wasi in C (wasm2c)?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, webassembly, wasi

I transfer a wasi-wasm to C file via `wasm2c`.

```bash
wasm2c test.wasm -o test.c
```

And I got a header file and a source C file. Part of the header file shows here.

```c
/* import: 'wasi_snapshot_preview1' 'args_get' */
u32 w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1_args_get(struct w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1*, u32, u32);

/* import: 'wasi_snapshot_preview1' 'args_sizes_get' */
u32 w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1_args_sizes_get(struct w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1*, u32, u32);

/* import: 'wasi_snapshot_preview1' 'clock_time_get' */
u32 w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1_clock_time_get(struct w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1*, u32, u64, u32);

/* import: 'wasi_snapshot_preview1' 'fd_close' */
u32 w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1_fd_close(struct w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1*, u32);
```

To compile the my own C file with the generated files, it requires implement of `wasi_snapshot_preview1_xxx`. Only declaration exists in the header file like above.

If I try to compile them without the definition, the error occurs:

```bash
clang main.c test.c wasm-rt-impl.c
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-740d87.o: in function `w2c_test_wasi_clock_time_get':
test.c:(.text+0x15b56c): undefined reference to `w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1_clock_time_get'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-740d87.o: in function `w2c_test_wasi_args_sizes_get':
test.c:(.text+0x18a07c): undefined reference to `w2c_wasi__snapshot__preview1_args_sizes_get'
...
```

How could I get the implement of these interfaces?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67756028/11107541

Comment: Not the same, I need C style wasi here. But that question was about the wasm style.

Comment: I'm seeing stuff like `__wasi_fd_close` defined in api.h in the wasi-sysroot include, but that naming doesn't match either. I would assume that it's some standard wasi SDK function, but wasm-rt-impl.c doesn't provide it either.

Comment: It just occurred to me: `wasm2c` knows about wasm, but probably not about WASI. There is a PR to add [uvwasi support](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/pull/2002) and there are projects like [wasm2native](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/wasm2native) and [w2c2](https://github.com/turbolent/w2c2) that try to address the same thing, but it might be that as of 1.0.34, wabt might not have a full WASI/C binding and requires users of the .h file to provide their own.

Comment: It looks that you don't link something

Comment: can you share `test.wasm` file?

Comment: Because there is nothing to link. I can only get `wasm-rt-impl.c` in wabt/wasm2c.

Comment: As Michael mentioned earlier, wabt might not have a full WASI/C binding and requires users of the .h file to provide their own. So we can't solve this currenly.

Comment: For the `test.wasm`, any C files compiled to WASI-WASM by clang can trigger this issue. So I didn't put a file here.

Comment: My intention was to use the interfaces in WASM, and I wanted to do it via wasm2c and then imported the interfaces from the generated C file to achieve that. Later I found out that this can actually be done through WASM Runtime (e.g. Wasmer). The problem itself maybe unsolvable at this moment.